# regex sorting by numbers embedded in line

Tags: regex

If I have a set of lines such as this:

```
hello 23 543 bye
cat 34 234 dog
meow 39 485 bark
```

How would I sort each line by the second number in each line? For example, I want the final solution to be

```
cat 34 234 dog
meow 39 485 bark
hello 23 543 bye
```

because 234<485<543

Any ideas?

Comment: In what programming language?  If this happens to be Linux command-line, then you can just use `sort -k2 -n`.

Comment: Just in regex expressions. Nope not homework, studying for a test so I'm trying to brainstorm questions that might be asked.

Comment: @user1161080: A regex doesn't do sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think regular expression search/replace syntax can be used to do sorting on its own. If you're processing a text file or something, try Oli Charlesworth's solution in the comments. If you're writing a script or a program, you can use regular expressions (or explode() or some other approach, depending on the language) to extract the relevant number from each line, turn it into an array key for that line, and then sort the array and reoutput the lines.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming those lines are contained in a file passed to a Perl script, this will do:

```
my @sorted = map $_->[0], 
    sort {$a->[3] <=> $b->[3]}
    map {chomp; [$_, split]} <>;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two components, the first one is to find the second number in each line.
For this one you can use a regex:

```
^[^0-9]*[0-9]+[^0-9]+([0-9]+)
```

Then you need to sort the lines by this extracted value.

You probably don't want to apply more than once for each line, so you would save the value together with the line (based on the language you can use a provided Pair class or write your own).
Then just sort (again based on the language there are different ways to sort).

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a programming language, I'll assume that you're open to a solution in any language.  Here's a quick Python solution (where `lines` is a list of the lines):

```
def second_num(line):
    found_first = False
    for token in line.split():
            if re.match(r'\d+', token):
                    if found_first:
                            return int(token)
                    found_first = True
    return 0

lines.sort(key=second_num) # Sorts lines in-place by the second number
```